# Python Sinusoidal white noise

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, gaussian

So what I'm doing is creating sine waves with normally distributed amplitudes and frequencies - within given ranges. Eg 5V with 2-10Hz. So my attempt at this is to get my function with the given amplitude and frequency and then run it till the first turning point. From there I calculate the next function and add the y value of the previous functions turning point (as a shift) so it starts from that point. My problem is for some of the function changes I get straight lines rather than curves. If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it. Just to note, I use 8ms increments for each value to be plotted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import serial

newlist = np.zeros(1)
timesnew = np.zeros(1)
volts = []

def main(amp, lowerFreq, upperFreq, time, incr):
    #Creates graph and saves it in newlist and timesnew
    amt = np.int(time / incr)
    list = []
    timels = []  # np.zeros(amt+amt)
    curtime = 0
    loweramp = -amp
    mu, sigma = 0, 1
    ybefore = 0
    rand = stats.truncnorm((loweramp - mu) / sigma, (amp - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    freqr = stats.truncnorm((lowerFreq - mu) / sigma, (upperFreq - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    i = 0
    while i < amt:
        # get amp
        thisAmp = rand.rvs()
        angleFreq = 2 * np.pi * freqr.rvs()
        xtp = np.arccos(0) / angleFreq #x value of turning point
        yval = thisAmp * np.sin(angleFreq * xtp)

        # check that yvalue(voltage) is okay to be used - is within +-amp range
        while not loweramp <= yval + ybefore <= amp:
            thisAmp = rand.rvs()
            angleFreq = 2 * np.pi * freqr.rvs()
            xtp = np.arccos(0) / angleFreq

            yval = thisAmp * np.sin(angleFreq * xtp)
        # now add values to list

        t = 0
        while t <= xtp:
            ynow = thisAmp * np.sin(angleFreq * t) + ybefore
            # print ynow
            list.append(ynow)
            curtime += incr
            timels.append(curtime)
            t += incr
            i += 1
            print i

        ybefore = ynow

    newlist = np.asarray(list)
    timesnew = np.asarray(timels)

    #a = np.column_stack((timesnew, newlist))

    np.savetxt("C://foo.csv", a, delimiter=";", fmt='%.10f')
    addvolts()
    plt.plot(timels,list)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(5, 1, 2, 25, 0.00008)
```

EDIT:
Basically here is the problem, after the turning point the function does not seem to be sinusodial (the line seems to be linear) and I can't understand why or atleast how to get the functions to end up being more "curvy" and not "sharp" at the turning points.

[image: My graph]

[image: zoomed]

I'm thinking maybe the function changes shouldn't be too different from the previous function but then I would lose the randomness. I'd like it to "look better" but I'm not sure how to achieve that unless I ran the frequencies in order. I'm trying to emulate a "whitenoise file" that was given to me as part of a job that I applied for - the whitenoise would be sent to a digital to analog converter and be used to test equipment. Obviously I didn't get the position BUT for knowledge purposes I want to complete this.

Here is the graph of the whitenoise file I was given - 700 mins long:

[image: Given file]

[image: zoomed]

[image: zoomed to show curves]
From the last pic the difference between mine and the given can be seen, I think I'm going to attempt to run each function for an entire period rather than a single turning point.

Comment: Your question lacks a sufficient problem description. When deleting the undefined lines, the code runs fine and produces a plot. I do not see any straight line. The problem is thus not reproducible. Can you provide a code that reproduces the issue and also a description of the problem that people have the chance to understand?

Comment: White noise by definition is completely irregular. It makes no sense to try to find a sinusoidal variant. Perhaps it is pink noise that you want to construct, white noise filtered to a frequency band?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have provided proof and further info to help explain my problem.

Comment: @LutzL I have provided an example of what I'm trying to emulate - I think it is pink noise that I'm attempting to create. Is there a better way to create this?

Comment: I still don't see an understandable problem description. I'm also completely lost in what the pictures are supposed to tell me. If you are looking for a solution to a problem from an assignment, it might be a good idea to actually share the assignment's text.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It was more of a test for a job. I was told to make a whitenoise generator that would produce whitenoise in a given frequency and amplitude range and that it should be similar to the file they provided - which I graphed and showed pictures of. From looking at the file I realised it is not linear but sinusodial, so I went about attempting to create a sinusodial function generator (the code attached)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True white noise is completely random, so trying to emulate white noise using some kind of function already is contradictory.

If the file you have is really supposed to be white noise than it has already undergone some kind of filtering. You can of course do the same in your program: Create some truely random numbers and use a filter function to obtain some "smoothing" effect.

For example you can use a Hann filter and colvolute the random noise with the filter. This is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.rand(1600)
win = scipy.signal.hann(15)
filtered = scipy.signal.convolve(y, win, mode='same') / sum(win)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax.plot(y, linestyle="-", marker=".", lw=0.3, markersize=1, color="r", alpha=0.5)
ax.set_title("random noise")

ax2.plot(y, linestyle="", marker=".", color="r", markersize=1)
ax2.plot(filtered)
ax2.set_title("filterred")

plt.show()
```

You might want to zoom in to better see the effect or use different parameter for the filter window.
[image]